# Passing function objects and using them in other functions in Python 3.8.4

Tags: python, lambda, function-object

I was looking at this question:

`cons(a, b)` constructs a pair, and `car(pair)` and `cdr(pair)` returns the first and last element of that pair. For example, `car(cons(3, 4))` returns 3, and `cdr(cons(3, 4))` returns 4.

Given this implementation of cons:

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a,b)
    return pair
```

Implement car and cdr.

I recognised the lambda expression, but I'm still unsure of how it works. The answer is given as:

```
def car(f):
    z = lambda x, y: x
    return f(z)

def cdr(f):
    z = lambda x, y: y
    return f(z)
```

If f is the function object, isn't passing z to f calling `lambda f : f(a,b)`, where z has 2 arguments but the other lambda only has 1 argument?

How does this solution work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to recognize how a pair is *represented*. A pair consists of *three* things: a first element, a second element, and a function. Most importantly, the two elements are *not* accessible "directly" (though see below): you can *only* get to them via the third member of the pair. That function takes *another* function, and returns the result of applying that function to the two "hidden" elements.

`car` takes the pair function and applies it to a function that returns the first of its two arguments.

`cdr` takes the pair function and applies it to a function which returns the second of its two arguments.

You can trace this as follows, made easier if you rewrite `cons = lambda a, b: lambda f: f(a, b)`:

```
car(cons(3, 5)) == cons(3, 5)(lambda x, y: x)
                == (lambda a, b: lambda f: f(a, b))(3, 5)(lambda x, y: x)
                == (lambda f: f(3, 5))(lambda x, y: x)
                == (lambda x, y: x)(3, 5)
                == 3


cdr(cons(3, 5)) == cons(3, 5)(lambda x, y: y)
                == (lambda a, b: lambda f: f(a, b))(3, 5)(lambda x, y: y)
                == (lambda f: f(3, 5))(lambda x, y: y)
                == (lambda x, y: y)(3, 5)
                == 5
```

---

`cons(3, 5)` essentially stores the values 3 and 5 in the `__closure__` attribute of the `pair` function it creates.

```
>>> p1 = cons(3, 5)
>>> p1.__closure__[0].cell_contents
3
>>> p1.__closure__[1].cell_contents
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's evaluate `car(cons(3, 4))`.

#### `cons(3, 4)`

```
a = 3
b = 4
def pair(f):
    return f(3, 4)
return pair
```

So right now we have `car(pair)`, where `pair` is:

```
def pair(f):
    return f(3, 4)
```

#### `car(pair)`

Let's see what happens in `car`:

```
f = pair
z = lambda x, y: x
return f(z)
```

So the last statement can be actually read as:

```
return pair(z)
```

or

```
return pair(lambda x, y: y)
```

Let's rewrite z as a regular function for the sake of simplicity:

```
def z(x, y):
    return x
```

#### `return pair(z)`

Now we run `pair` with `z` as parameter.

Remember, `pair` is defined as:

```
def f(n):
    return n(3, 4)
```

So n = z, and we should return:

```
z(3, 4)
```

What `z` does is actually "return the first parameter".

And... Here you have it :)